# How can I get bitmap from .resources (not .resx) file

Tags: c#, .net, resources, reflector

I have opened assembly with reflector and saved some .resources files to my hard drive. There is some bitmaps in there, how can I get them from saved .resources file?
I'd like to save them as image (.bmp) file via code or some program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the [PowerCommands for Reflector](http://powercommands.codeplex.com/) and save the resources as a .resx file - then open it in Visual Studio.

Comment: I just added a set of commands to the PowerCommands project called "Open in VSxx" that should work for Vs 2005, 2008 for 2010 that will save the step of saving the resources as an resx file - then having to open that file in VS. The new commands extract the resources file, converts it to an resx and then opens it in VS for you.

Answer (score 1):

check this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324567

OR check this

```
using System.Resources;
using System.Reflection;

ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("YourProgramName.ProgramResources",
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

rm.GetObject("my_icon_name");
```